# QAudioOutput error: snd_pcm_hw_params_set_buffer_time_near: err = -22

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, blackberry-10, alsa

I use the following code for playing a WAV file:

```
inputFile.setFileName("/accounts/1000/appdata/com.example.SoundR.testDev_mple_SoundRe6609254/data/tracks/rec.wav");
inputFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);

QAudioFormat format;
// Set up the format, eg.
format.setSampleRate(16000);
format.setChannelCount(1);
format.setSampleSize(16);
format.setCodec("audio/pcm");
format.setByteOrder(QAudioFormat::LittleEndian);
format.setSampleType(QAudioFormat::UnSignedInt);

QAudioDeviceInfo info(QAudioDeviceInfo::defaultOutputDevice());
if (!info.isFormatSupported(format)) {
    qWarning() << "Raw audio format not supported by backend, cannot play audio.";
    format = info.nearestFormat(format);
}

audioOutput = new QAudioOutput(format, this);

connect(audioOutput,SIGNAL(stateChanged(QAudio::State)),SLOT(finishedPlaying(QAudio::State)));
connect(audioOutput, SIGNAL(stateChanged(QAudio::State)), this, SLOT(handleStateChanged(QAudio::State)));

audioOutput->start(&inputFile);
```

But I get an error:

```
"QAudioOutput: snd_pcm_hw_params_set_buffer_time_near: err = -22"
```

I got this from [this tutorial](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qaudiooutput.html).

Comment: Did you Google for "snd_pcm_hw_params_set_buffer_time_near: err = -22"? There are many hits indicating this is an ALSA error.

Comment: yes, but nothing that could help me. there isn't description of this error

Comment: Did you try looking into ALSA's source code? It's open source, you can download it, find the function definition using a text search, and inspect the code to see how it returns error -22.

Comment: Does `aplay rec.wav` work?

Comment: According to the Qt documentation ``QAudioOutput`` is not supported on Blackberry OS yet (it seems very low priority as the documentation states this since 2 years).